# Display alert message if checkbox isn't checked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show a message if the checkmark on this page is not checked - https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/rental-cars/oahu/honolulu-airport.htm

See where it says "I'm aware Alamo has additional fees, paid directly to Alamo at the counter when picking up the vehicle."

On a static page the script below works correctly (for example if you download the page and place the code in the body). But when the page is live, it is not working.

```
<script>
$('#dnn_ctr367_CartQuickView_anchBookNow').click(function () {
    if (!$('.cartcheckbox').is(':checked')) {
        alert('Please check the box - I\'m aware Alamo has additional fees, paid directly to Alamo at the counter when picking up the vehicle.');
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

EDIT:
When you click on the book now button there is text that appears on top of the cart (that's in case you didn't put any of the required information). So it seems this text is part of a program that ignores the script above. Is there a way to make my script to activate before the other one so if you click the green button you will right away see the pop up message?

Comment: do you get an error on the console?

Comment: Probably because the ID of the element you've attached the click event changes in a Live environment.

Comment: It's because `$('.cartcheckbox')` is not a checkbox, it's a `span` containing the checkbox - try changing it to the id of the checkbox (or `input[type="checkbox"]` if you only have one checkbox in the page

Comment: I would even be more specific with the selector, just in case more features are added to the site in the future: `$('.cartcheckbox > input[type=checkbox]')`. I would also suggest using `.on("click", ...)` in case you need a delegate. Best to code with an eye on the future so you don't have to revisit every piece of code written.

Comment: Agreed, even so, if more than one checkbox is added within the same `span` then more changes would be required to the code but the future is hard to predict ;)

Comment: @ochi Yup, but at least we can try! :)

Comment: @DrewKennedy in agreement again :)

Comment: After your edit, I think you need provide a [mcve] in this case - the code above is not enough to reproduce the issue - or ask a separate question (since it looks like a different issue, not related to the checkbox) - Aside, did you refresh browser cache? (CTRL+F5) - I went to the page and the alert is shown first (before submitting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `$('.cartcheckbox')` is not a checkbox, it's a `span` containing the checkbox

Try changing it to the id of the checkbox (or `input[type="checkbox"]` if you only have one checkbox in the page.

As in:

```
$('#dnn_ctr367_CartQuickView_anchBookNow').on('click', function () {
    // update selector below
    if (!$('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
        alert('Please check the box - I\'m aware Alamo has additional fees, paid directly to Alamo at the counter when picking up the vehicle.');
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you have more than one checkbox on the page, try changing it to

```
if (!$('.cartcheckbox').find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {...}
```

to select only the checkbox inside your relevant `span`

**Updated code** below to include trigger button

```js
$(function() {

  $('#dnn_ctr367_CartQuickView_anchBookNow').on('click', function() {
    // updated selector below    
    if (!$('.cartcheckbox').find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {

      alert('Please check the box - I\'m aware Alamo has additional fees, paid directly to Alamo at the counter when picking up the vehicle.');

      return false;

    } else {
      alert('checkbox is checked');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="cartcheckbox"><input id="dnn_ctr367_CartQuickView_ucCollector_I'mawareAlamohasadditionalfees,paiddirectlytoAlamoatthecounterwhenpickingupthevehicle." type="checkbox" name="dnn:ctr367:CartQuickView:ucCollector:I'mawareAlamohasadditionalfees,paiddirectlytoAlamoatthecounterwhenpickingupthevehicle."></span>
<br/>
<div align="center">
  <a id="dnn_ctr367_CartQuickView_anchBookNow" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="#">
    <button>
      <div class="TBook">Book Now</div>
    </button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Good catch! I think a good idea would be to use .on('click', ...) since I believe the placement of the javascript is part of the problem since it runs before the element has been rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this but still not working. When I click the green button I only see the message on top "Please enter a text value for Rental Car Pickup Time
Please enter a text value for Rental Car Return Time
Please enter a text value for Driver Name" but my pop out message doesn't appear.

Comment: @Parlanchina I added a running example.  See code running.  It works, are you sure you do not have errors in console? there is some other JS events executing on the button press, are you sure those are not interfering?

Comment: @kb thank you! updated answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, ochi this works fine! The only thing that shows up when you check the box is "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" is there a way to get rid of it and just proceed to checkout once the box is checked?

Comment: Thank you very much, ochi! You have been a great help!

Comment: @Parlanchina you are welcome -  glad I could help :)